would last x could last
In the context of the text below, can either of these two expressions be used to say that a relationship was not expected to last longer than it actually did?
Example 1:
Our relationship was fun and even pleasant for a while, but now, as I look back, I have to admit that there was no chance we would last. We were two completely different people, with different opinions on just about everything.
Example 2:
Our relationship was fun and even pleasant for a while, but now, as I look back, I have to admit that there was no chance that we could last. We were two completely different people, with different opinions on just about everything.

In your first paragraph, are you trying to say ‘that a relationship was not expected to last longer than it actually did?’

Yes, that's right. Sorry for not being able to make that clear.

don't worry and don't need to apologise :)

Thank you Seowjooheng and Peter. Peter, with regard to "unwillingness" (a new word for me indeed :)), yes, it could actually be used as one of the elements that led to the separation, but I believe that the main element is the realization (and possible resignation about it) that the subject makes about the difference in personalities and opinions between the two.

In fact, my original text would go something like this: "Our relationship was fun and even pleasant for a while, but now, looking back, I have to admit that there was no chance of us staying together for long. We were two completely different people, with different opinions on almost everything." And I wanted to know if one of the expressions "There was no chance that we could last" or "there was no chance that we would last" could be used as a simplified form for "there was no chance that of us staying together for long".


... there was no chance we would last.


... there was no chance we could last.

We omit the second that in example 2 to simplify comparison.
Edit
The examples have slightly different meanings.
The second leans more towards just their inability; the first is more of a prediction and may include encumbrances like unwillingness.

Would in that sentence is a future tense. If we simplify it, We can't last indeed points to inability; but We won't last is merely a future prediction. The reason for the prediction is unstated. Elements such as unwillingness are possible, but we would only know that from the surrounding context.

Thanks, @Peter Kirkpatrick.  I have edited my answer.
